# Make widget always expand to screen border

Tags: flutter, size, overflow, expand

Is there a way to make a widget, for instance a Container, always expand to a screen border, not dependent of a specific widget tree structure?

Answer (score 1):

Containers impose constraints on their children so you can't make a child's width bigger than its parent when it is a container

some tips :
you can use the Expanded widget to take all the remaining space

to take all the size of the screen you can use width: double.infinity

Answer (score 1):

As they said already, in `Container()` you can use `width: double.infinity` or `width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width`. But for this, the parent of Container can't have a size smaller than the screen.